# difference in difference endline sample size calculation

Tags: sample-size, difference-in-difference

Im looking for feedback about a sampling challenge.

Im designing an end of project survey - the design was a repeated measures (baseline and endline) non-equivalent control group design.

Interest in using a difference in difference analysis and also sampling as few as possible persons at endline.

The main outcome variable and is a proportion (children 6-59 months stunted) and was .62 at baseline.

The baseline collected data from 1423 persons in program area and from 423 persons in control area (from 1638 households in program and 547 households in control).

Looking at a difference in proportion of 10% (or from .62 to .52) from baseline to endline as the goal.

The design effect at baseline was estimated at 1 but should actually be 1.5 or 2.

Thanks for any thoughts or feedback.

~Todd